# How to add subsets of a data frame into ggplot in a stepwise manner

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've got a data frame I'd like to plot out, but it is so large that the plot is a little confusing and I'd like to build it step by step in order to visualize and compare the steps.

Here is some dummy data:

```
 V1<-rnorm(50)
 V2<-rnorm(50)
 V3<-c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10),rep("C",10),rep("D",10),rep("E",10))
 V4<-V2+.1
 DF<-data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4)
```

My plot code looks like this:

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=V1,y=V2,size=V4,label=DF$V3),legend=FALSE)+
scale_y_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
scale_x_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
geom_point(color="black",fill='red',shape=21)+
geom_text(size=2)+theme_bw()+
scale_size(range = c(5, 20))
```

Which has all my desired aesthetics, but is too confusing too look at. So I break the up the data frame by the character variable, which would be my variable of interest.

```
S<-split(DF,DF$V3)
```

Now ideally I'd like to start with a blank plot, and then add on the data for A, then B, then C,D, and E stepwise so I can print out each step of the way. Each plot having the same aesthetics and drawing their size from V4 and labels from V3.

I tried adding on layers with successive geom_point additions like so:

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=V1,y=V2,size=V4))+
scale_y_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
scale_x_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
theme_bw()+
geom_blank()+

geom_point(data=S$"A",color="black",fill='red',shape=21)+
aes(label=S$'A')+
geom_text(size=2)+
scale_size(range=c(5,20))+

geom_point(data=S$'B',color="black",fill='red',shape=21)+
aes(label=S$'B')+
geom_text(size=2)+
scale_size(range=c(5,20))
```

Which works if I just leave it at the first line for geom_point for both A and B, but as soon as I start to add labels and other details I quickly get errors.

Answer (score 3):

You could plot first subset and store it as object.

```
p<-ggplot(S$A,aes(x=V1,y=V2,size=V4,label=V3),legend=FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
  scale_x_continuous( limits = c(-3, 3))+
  geom_point(color="black",fill='red',shape=21)+
  geom_text(size=2)+theme_bw()+
  scale_size(range = c(5, 20))
```

Then use `%+%` to update your plot. `do.call()` in second example is used to get one data frame from the list elements.

```
#to replace subset A with subset B
p %+% S$B 

#to replace subset A with first three subsets    
p %+% do.call(rbind,S[1:3])
```